# IllegalStateException using Room and RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm having an issue when accesing the Room DAOs in my app.
I get this error even though I'm doing the operation in a background thread via rxjava:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

I'm trying to use a clean architecture via MVP in the app and I call the use case that make that operation in a background thread.

More info:

The classes involverd are:

[RecipesPresenter.java](https://github.com/fjoglar/baking-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fjoglar/bakingapp/recipes/RecipesPresenter.java)

[UpdateRecipes.java](https://github.com/fjoglar/baking-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fjoglar/bakingapp/recipes/domain/UpdateRecipes.java) which extends from [UseCase.java](https://github.com/fjoglar/baking-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fjoglar/bakingapp/UseCase.java).

And finally [RecipesLocalDataSource.java](https://github.com/fjoglar/baking-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fjoglar/bakingapp/data/source/local/RecipesLocalDataSource.java)

I need some help here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `just` which takes an already created/computed value. So basically you do the computation on the caller thread and you wrap **the result** into an `Observable`. (I can't imagine why this logical misunderstanding comes up so often as there is no mainstream language that would defer a calculation between a regular parenthesis.)

Do like this instead:

```java
@Override
public Observable<Boolean> updateRecipes(List<JsonRecipe> jsonRecipes) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        mRecipeDb.runInTransaction(() ->
            deleteOldAndInsertNewRecipesTransaction(jsonRecipes));
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RxJava does not mean you´re doing Async process, in fact RxJava is sync by default.

If you want make an operation async you need to use operators `subscribeOn` which will subscribe your observable to be run in another thread, or use observerOn to specify which operation you want to be done async.

An example

```
/**
 * Once that you set in your pipeline the observerOn all the next steps of your pipeline will be executed in another thread.
 * Shall print
 * First step main
 * Second step RxNewThreadScheduler-2
 * Third step RxNewThreadScheduler-1
 */
@Test
public void testObservableObserverOn() throws InterruptedException {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(1)
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("First step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Second step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Third step " + Thread.currentThread()
                    .getName()))
            .subscribe();
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see some examples of both here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java